# Adding a delay before keyup() fires in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onkeyup, timedelay

I have read through some of the suggested questions but I am not sure exactly how to implement them:

- [(jquery/js) - get text from field on keyup, but with delay for further typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101259/jquery-js-get-text-from-field-on-keyup-but-with-delay-for-further-typing)
- [How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay)
- [How to trigger an onkeyup event that's delayed until a user pauses their typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620602/javascript-jquery-make-an-ajax-request-when-a-user-is-typing-in-a-textarea)

I have 8 textboxes, 7 are used for numeric input and the 8th is a total. 
i.e. 7.5 + 7.5 + 7.5 + 7.5 + 7.5 + 0.0 + 0.0 = 37.5

I have the jQuery working so that it monitors each textboxes keyup() and adds all of the values and calculates the total.

I decided that I want to format the users input in the 7 textboxes so that it comes out like #.# if they enter "1" or ".1" i.e. "1.0" or "0.1".

The problem is that I need to add a delay before the input is formatted and I am unsure as to how I do it with javascript and/or jquery.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            var content = $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val() != content) {

                    content = $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val();
                    $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));
                }
            });

            var content2 = $('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val() != content2) {

                    content2 = $('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content2);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));
                }
            });

            var content3 = $('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val() != content3) {

                    content3 = $('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content3);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));
                }
            });

            var content4 = $('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val() != content4) {

                    content4 = $('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content4);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));
                }
            });

            var content5 = $('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val() != content5) {

                    content5 = $('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content5);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));
                }
            });

            var content6 = $('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val() != content6) {

                    content6 = $('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content6);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));
                }
            });

            var content7 = $('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val() != content7) {

                    content7 = $('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content7);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Ideally, I would like to fire this line:

```
$('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
```

After a specified time e.g. 100ms

---

**Updated working code:**

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var delay = (function () {
            var timer = 0;
            return function (callback, ms) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
            };
        })();

        $(function () {

            var content = $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val() != content) {

                    content = $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));

                    delay(function () {
                        $('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    }, 750);
                }
            });

            var content2 = $('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val() != content2) {

                    content2 = $('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content2);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));

                    delay(function () {
                        $('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    }, 750);
                }
            });

            var content3 = $('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val() != content3) {

                    content3 = $('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content3);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));

                    delay(function () {
                        $('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    }, 750);
                }
            });

            var content4 = $('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val() != content4) {

                    content4 = $('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content4);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));

                    delay(function () {
                        $('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    }, 750);
                }
            });

            var content5 = $('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val() != content5) {

                    content5 = $('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content5);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));

                    delay(function () {
                        $('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    }, 750);
                }
            });

            var content6 = $('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val() != content6) {

                    content6 = $('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content6);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));

                    delay(function () {
                        $('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    }, 750);
                }
            });

            var content7 = $('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val();
            $('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').keyup(function () {
                if ($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val() != content7) {

                    content7 = $('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val();
                    var hoursMon = new Number(content7);
                    var hoursTue = new Number($('input[id*="txtMondayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursWed = new Number($('input[id*="txtWednesdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursThu = new Number($('input[id*="txtThursdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursFri = new Number($('input[id*="txtFridayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSat = new Number($('input[id*="txtSaturdayHours"]').val());
                    var hoursSun = new Number($('input[id*="txtTuesdayHours"]').val());

                    $('input[id*="txtTotalWorkingHours"]').val(parseFloat(hoursMon.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursTue.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursWed.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursThu.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursFri.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSat.toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(hoursSun.toFixed(2)));

                    delay(function () {
                        $('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val((new Number($('input[id*="txtSundayHours"]').val())).toFixed(2));
                    }, 750);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: On a completely unrelated note. I would recommend DRYing out your code. You do the exact same thing 7 times, and in that process, you do another thing 7 times each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in a timeout. Then on subsequent 1`keyup` events, clear the timeout and reset it.

That is what this one is doing [How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library's [debounce function](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce).

Comment: Thank you for that library, I have decided to go with Daniel's suggestion as it is using existing jQuery functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ben Alman's jQuery throttle / debounce: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/.